# Visual Studio online can't add existing project

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I've tried literally everything to add my git project to VS 2013 online, but all the guides don't help. I am missing the buttons to add my project to source control, or add it to my remote. I also tried manually adding my project to the visual studio online as a remote, but git rejected added it with other errors. Could someone give me a quick and simple step by step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your Visual Studio refuses to add and nothing works, the command line git can help.

Note, before you can use the command line, you'll need to [enable basic authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286572(v=vs.120).aspx#setup_basic_auth) for your account.

[image]

If you already have an existing Git repository, you can push it to the server.
From Visual Studio
You can Push a repository after connecting with Team Explorer and adding the Git repo to your list of Local Git Repositories.
From the command line

You can push the project using the following commands:

```
git remote add origin https://{username-here}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/{AppName}

git push -u origin --all
```

Note: (%20 for spaces in url)